# formatter returns the entire html slickgrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid, formatter

I am trying to highlight a cell if it has been edited in slickgrid. I am trying to do it with custom formatter.

```
function determineEdit(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
    var varRow = dataView.getItem(row);
    if(varRow.isUpdated == 'true'){
    return "<span style='color:red'>" + value + "</span>";
    }else{
    return value;
    }
}
```

When the grid renders the entire span tag is displayed a text in the cell.
Please let me know what i am doing wrong.
Thanks,
KG

Comment: your code seems fine...just **alert** or **console.log** your **value**. May be you can get some clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a VF page. The code snippet is correct. The actual problem was else where. I had used VF tags in javascript to dynamically create some elements. That resulted in javascript syntax errors while parsing. Now that i have changed them to standard HTML tags the code is working fine. Thanks for the help.